# T-SQL Date Difference between rows using row number same table

Tags: sql-server

This is my SQL Server view:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY N.PHN
                       ORDER BY N.CheckDate ASC) AS RowNumber,*
FROM
    (SELECT 
         dbo.Flu.Day AS CheckDate, 
         dbo.Flu.PHN AS PHN
     FROM 
         dbo.Flu
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         dbo.Patient ON dbo.Flu.PHN = dbo.Patient.PHN) AS N;
```

Result:

[image]

I am trying to find the difference between two consecutive dates in days for each PHN based on `RowNumber`; keeping in mind that some PHN will only have one `RowNumber`.

Comment: Why do you join to dbo.Patient.PHN since you are not selecting from it?

Comment: I am selecting other columns from dbo.Patient.  Just to simplify my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [`LAG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) window function:

```
SELECT f.Day AS CheckDate, f.PHN AS PHN,
  DATEDIFF(
    day, 
    COALESCE(LAG(f.Day) OVER (PARTITION BY f.PHN ORDER BY f.Day ASC), f.Day),
    f.Day
  ) diff 
FROM dbo.Flu f LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Patient p 
ON f.PHN = p.PHN
```

Comment: I got this error: The conversion of the nvarchar value '2222222222' overflowed an int column.  PHN is nvarchar(20).  2222222222 has one row.

Comment: Worked great, except I made a mistake in my question; I am trying to get the difference between dates in days for each PHN.  My apology, I corrected the question.